# Are all 'feeders' leveled up cards?

Tags: guardian-cross

I've read that 4* 'feeders' are cards that are Lvl 55, as that helps grows the 5* cards. I also came across some trading posts for 2* & 3* feeders, are these also leveled up versions and if so, to what level?

Also, why are the 4* feeders leveled up to 55, since there are higher levels in the game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"2* feeders" and "3* feeders" refer to lvl 1 guardians.

Lvl 55 is the maximum level for 4* guardians. [Rebirth](http://guardian-cross.wikia.com/wiki/Rebirth)  allows 4* guardians to reach lvl 60, but that is uncommon for 4*s.

Comment: Also, at the time of posting this, Rebirth is not available on Android yet.